# .htaccess RewriteRule for multiple parameters added in javascript as non slash

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

This question might be a duplicate. But I did not find any solution for my problem. I try to add RewriteRule to htaccess file that will be combine slashed static parameters with non slashed parameters added in javascript by `window.history.replaceState( {} , '', '');` for choosed filters.
I got two static parameters named as 'p' and 'a'. For that i write rule:

`RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z\_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\-]*)$ index.php?p=$1&a=$2 [NC,L]`.

But i need to add non slashed parameters for friendly url, that gonna be create only in js and used for back action in history. I would like to that url looks like:

*www.page.com/category/pen.html?colour=green*

and that should be as non friendly:

*www.page.com/index.php?p=category&a=pen&colour=green*

and that parameters after parameter 'a' could be many, but should be after .html extension.

I don't found any solution so far for that problem. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)(/([A-Za-z0-9\-\,]+))?$ /index.php?p=$1&a=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

That works!

Comment: You can use the `QSA` flag in your rule, to get any already existing query string of the original rule merged with the one you are creating yourself.

Comment: Is something like this ok? `RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z\_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\-\,]*)\.html?$ index.php?p=$1&a=$2& [QSA,L]` Added '.html?' in first part and '&' in second part after parameters .Should that work properly?

Comment: That is not going to keep any existing query string that was part of the originally requested URL already.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for suggestion, so i edit my htaccess file (in edit section) but i got 500 Internal error

Comment: Your first rule matches _everything_ that could possibly be requested indiscriminately with `^(.*)$`, so you created an endless redirect loop here.

Comment: @04FS please check edit 2 section. As before i got 500 error, but admin subdirectory seems to work fine. Thank you for any help. Im done...

Comment: `www.page.com/subdirectory` is not a host name, only the `www.page.com` part of that is.

Comment: Ok i got that, but as before  500 error exists, could that be because it's work in subdirectory?

Comment: Check the error log to find out what the actual error is.

Comment: For my bad, I don't have any possible to check server log, that was my first idea but no access

Comment: Then ask your hoster, or set up a local dev system to replicate what you got in production. Guesswork without the actual error message is never fun.

Comment: Ok, i done what you suggest, thank you. I got error RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters. Now i try to check what flag is problem, any hints appreciated

Comment: `[L, QSA]` - there mustn’t be a space in there, needs to be `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Yeah i notice that but forgot to edit code, BTW thanks for response, now i have problem with duplicates url values (check edit section)

Comment: Ok, that works, if you want @04FS You can add answer with QSA flag and i will accept that as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QSA` flag in your rule, to get any already existing query string of the original rule merged with the one you are creating yourself.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.